# fgets() causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux

In college I am learning communication between processes, and I have this exercise where I have to get a parent process link to a child through a pipe, the child runs the cmd `sort fx.txt` and sends to the parent the output, which the parent should print.

The content of `fx.txt` is

```
b
a
```

After some search, found out `popen()` would be a good choice, and following some example code this is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIZE 255

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char *cmd = "sort fx.txt";
    file = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("error opening pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *str;

    //print sorted lines
    while (fgets(str, SIZE, file) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", str); // \n already stored in str
    }
    pclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

I get segmentation fault on the line of `fgets()`.
After that, I randomly tried to fix it by creating another pointer and assigning the return of `fgets()` to it.

The change is as follows:

```
    char *str;
    char *s;
    //print sorted lines
    while ((s = fgets(str, SIZE, file)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", str); // \n already stored in str
    }
```

It worked and the output is:

```
a
b
```

I would be thankful if someone could explain me this behaviour.

Comment: `char *str;` That's an unintialised pointer. You can't use it in `fgets` until you have some memory buffer and assign the address to that pointer. Something like `char str[SIZE];` or `char *str = malloc(SIZE);`.

Comment: @kaylum It's working now. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str;
```

Is an uninitialized pointer. When you call `fgets` with it as an argument, you cause undefined behaviour. Allocate some actual space and use that:

```
char str[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
```

Where `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` is something reasonable for your program.

Comment: Why not `SIZE` since that was already in use in the call to `fgets()`?